# kotlin combine flow has a slight delay from the dependent flows, thus causing issue in android compose view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I have a **ListScreen** which displays list items loaded from internet with the option to filter the items.

So, I have two states here: **future** and **filter** (see ViewModel code). My **list** state is combined flow of these two states, with initial value of empty list.

In my **Compose** screen, I want to show different view when **list** state is empty, otherwise the list items. The issue is that, when **future** state changes from **LOADING** to **SUCCESS**, the **list** state doesn't change from empty list to future result immediately, but a slight delay is observed. Due to this slight delay, sometimes the empty list screen is shown for a slight moment (See comment in Compose code).

ViewModel code:

```kotlin
class ListViewModel<T>(
    val path: String,
    val repository: MyRepository<T>,
): ViewModel() {
    enum class State { LOADING, SUCCESS, FAILURE }

    private val _futureState = MutableStateFlow(State.LOADING)
    val futureState = _futureState.asStateFlow()
    
    private lateinit var _futureError: Throwable
    val futureError get() = _futureError
    
    private lateinit var _futureResult: List<T>
    
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
            try {
                _futureResult = repository.get(path) // suspend fun returns List<T>
                _futureState.update { State.SUCCESS }
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _futureError = error
                _futureState.update { State.FAILURE }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private val _filterState = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val filterState = _filterState.asStateFlow()
    
    fun setFilter(value: String?) {
        _filterState.update { value }
    }
    
    val listState = combine(futureState, filterState) { state, filter ->
        if (state == State.SUCCESS) {
            if (!filter.isNullOrBlank()) {
                _futureResult.filter { 
                    // filter predicate
                }  
            } else _futureResult
        } else emptyList()
    }.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(1000),
        emptyList(),
    )
}
```

Compose code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> ListScreen(
    path: String,
    repository: MyRepository<T>,
) {
    val vm: ListViewModel<T> = viewModel(
        factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                ListViewModel(path, repository)
            }
        }
    )

    val state by vm.futureState.collectAsState()
    val filter by vm.filterState.collectAsState()
    val list by vm.listState.collectAsState()

    Scaffold {
        when (state) {
            State.LOADING -> { /* loading screen */ }
            State.FAILURE -> { /* error message screen */ }
            State.SUCCESS -> {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    /* no results found screen */

                    // issue: when state changes from LOADING -> SUCCESS,
                    // this screen is shown for a very short duration

                    // note: the issue is only observed sometimes 
                } else {
                    /* list items screen */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```